# Was that Cybermats that I heard?

Tags: doctor-who

In the 11th Doctor story [The Almost People](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b011lqwt) I could have sworn the Doctor muttered something about [Cybermats](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Cybermat). Was I hallucinating?

This was at the beginning of the episode when the Doctor and his "ganger" were confronting each other. I think the Doctor said something about them being telepathic.

Comment: Need a little more info than this...around what part in the episode?

Comment: @IanPugsley it's right at the start when the two Doctors are getting used to each other.

Comment: It was shortly after he said to "reverse the polarity of the neutron flow".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes - it was said (as Richard and Keen said in their comments). I don't think it is significant to the story. It was a sort of post regeneration (although this was not regeneration) babble pulling things from the Doctor's past

Answer (score 7):

Yes you heard it (no, you weren't hallucinating).  [Cybermats](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Cybermat), mentioned by the Doctor's Ganger, are rodent-like killers created by the Cybermen.

These creatures were first seen in [The Tomb of the Cybermen](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562967/) (2nd Doctor).

Comment: Thank you for telling me when the Cybermats where first introduced - but its not actually helpful.

Comment: @Lekarz the literal answer to your question is "no, you weren't hallucinating".  I provided a *more useful* answer, that (a) says yes they were mentioned and by whom, (b) provides a link to a page that contains a lot of information about them, and (c) explains that these are not new to Doctor Who.  Please edit your question if you wanted something else.

Answer (score 0):

See [page Series 6 on TARDIS Wiki](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Series_6_%28Doctor_Who%29)

They are returning in the second-to-last episode. They just started randomly talking about them - maybe as a hint.

Comment: Good point - I think you are referring to "A Good Man Goes to War" where the Cybermen briefly appear. However, I don't think this is significant - and certainly no cybermats.